# Java choice between overloading methods from generic class

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection, static-polymorphism

The following code could not be compiled: in generic class LM Java unable to resolve which of "static server()" methods to call. On the other hand, I'm not able to add any "instanceof" or "isAssignableFrom" code too, because "DB" is generic.

I think, it is main ERROR in Java - they should have added something like a switch (DB instanceof Class) internally in byte-code. The one thing why they didn't - it is if list of possible real parameters is unknown in compile-time.

What could be a work-around? Things like Unsafe or (even Javassist) are possible, though Javassist is less preferable.

```
public class UnitTest {
    interface A {}
    static class B implements A {}
    static class C implements A {}
    final static A s = new B(); // instance

    public class LM<DB extends A> {
        DB get() {
            return server((DB) null); // this doesn't work
        }
    }

    static <DB extends B> DB server(DB NULL) {
        return (s instanceof B ? (DB) s : null);
    }

    static <DB extends C> DB server(DB NULL) {
        return (s instanceof C ? (DB) s : null);
    }

    @Test
    public void useNoContext() throws IOException {
        B b = server((B) null); // this works
        C c = server((C) null); // this works

        LM<B> lb = new LM<>();
        B b1 = lb.get();

        LM<C> lc = new LM<>();
        C c1 =  lc.get(); // problem!
    }
}
```

The problem is THERE ARE A LOT of instances of "LM", so it is not possible to have dynamic reference to "DB" instance, it is absolute necessary to have it in compile-time.

I have as well tried to use Lambdas with generic parameter "DB", but with no apparent success.

Comment: Ah, the classic "my design doesn't work like I want in Java, therefore Java is wrong" ... If you want reified type information at runtime, a common way to achieve that is to require a `Class<DB> clazz` object to be provided then you can do something like `clazz.isInstance(obj)`.

Comment: Recommended read: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score -1):

The main problem in Java is construction "if (object instanceof DB)", where "DB" is generic, does not work.

```
public class UnitTest {
    interface A {}
    static class B implements A {}
    static class C implements A {}
    final static A s = new B(); // instance

    public class LM<DB extends A> {
        DB get() {
            return server((DB) null);
        }
    }

    private <DB extends A> DB server(DB NULL) {
        return (DB) s; // Typecast error must be here

        // This doesn't work for type "C"
        //try {
        //    return (DB) ((B) s);
        //} catch (ClassCastException e) {
        //    return null;
        //}
    }

    @Test
    public void useNoContext() throws IOException {
        LM<B> lb = new LM<>();
        B b = lb.get(); // this works

        LM<C> lc = new LM<>();
        C c = lc.get(); // Java BIG HOLE! Typecast error just here (unpredictable behavior)

    }
}
```

Comment:
It is just an example. The point is that we should NEVER receive object of wrong type in "LM<C>" : if we need type "C", we must receive either instance of type "C" or null, or exception, or something like this. Else we will catch typecast exception or unpredictable behavior in runtime. In my mind it is big hole in Java.

Comment: This is even less comprehensible than the code of your question. What’s the point of casting `a`, which is known to refer to a `B` instance, to the type `C`, which will predictably fail? So you always end up returning a new instance of `C`, which in not guaranteed to be `DB`. Of course, as long as all a `new LM<B>().set()` would do, is printing the object, you won’t notice that it isn’t a `B` instance.

Comment: It is just an example. The point is that we should NEVER receive object of wrong type in LM<C> : if we need type "C", we must receive either instance of type "C" or null, or exception, or something like this. Else we will catch typecast exception or unpredictable behavior in runtime. In my mind it is big hole in Java.

Comment: Apparently, you don’t even know what you want. You keep editing your code over and over again. Sometimes, the type parameter is used as method parameter, sometimes as return type, then for both. The actual purpose of this code stays a mystery.

Comment: This was the last modification, have a look. There was no significant changes - just for readable code.

Comment: So what’s the purpose of a method like `private <DB extends A> DB server(DB NULL)` that ignores the argument and returns a `B` instance no matter whether it is compatible to the *caller-chosen* `DB`? Do you understand that with this declaration, I could write `List<String> list = new UnitTest().server(null);` and not even get a compiler warning?

Comment: Method "server()" must return instance of appropriate datatype (there may be several static variables or a list of instances). In the first message typized null works well - it call approrpiate method.